# How to handle NULL values when sorting?

Tags: python, sql, sorting, null

I am looking for a way to return NULL values last when sorting either DESC or ASC in SQL (the envelopping code is in Python) and maybe be able to retun the NULL values first depending on some config

I tried replacing the NULL values with numeric values but in the long run I found that it is not a suitable solution since in some cases I need to traceback the origin of the NULL, why I have it and putting a numeric value could influence the work of someone else and give inaccurate results.

```
if request.sort:
    sql += " order by " + ', '.join([sort.split(':')[0] + " " + sort.split(':')[1] for sort in request.sort])

return sql
```

Comment: Could you share a small data sample and expected output?

Comment: You sorting in Python or SQL?

Comment: I am sorting in sql but the code is in Python. I want to have the sorted numeric values first and the NULL values at last after them or have the NULLS first and then the sorted values in order.

Comment: This is a sample of the api post call I am making to get the results:  {
    "indicators": ["mP"],
    "limit": 10,
    "sort": ["mP:asc"],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate way on your implementation use `union all` between filtered data

```
.... from table_name where column is not null order by column <desc/asc>
UNION ALL
.... from table_name where column is null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the numeric replacement of nulls and keep the original values if you only do the replacement in the order by syntax. The resulting SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM Table
ORDER BY COALESCE(col1, -99)
```

Also found a [nice reference](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-order_by) for sorting with nulls.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
create table test(col1 varchar(10),col2 float)

insert into test
values('A',1),
('C',2),
('D',null),
('F',4)
```

instead of sorting like this:

```
select * from test order by col2 desc
select * from test order by col2 asc
```

sort using a case statement as shown below if you want to get null at the top:

```
select * from test order by case when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end, col2 desc
select * from test order by case when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end, col2 asc
```

to get null at the bottom:

```
select * from test order by case when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end desc, col2 desc
select * from test order by case when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end desc, col2 asc
```